# Vertical viewport was given unbounded height for SizedBox inside container

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to insert a `ListView` to take the remaining space of a `Column`. Using `Expanded(child: ListView)` does not work, I have to use a `SizedBox` with a `height`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      ExpandableListTitle(title: widget.title),
      Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 10, right: 5),
          child: SizedBox(
              height: 280, // <<<<<< If I take this out, I get error
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                children: widget.children,
              )))
    ]);
  }
```

Where `ExpandableListTitle` is just a container:

```
ExpandableListTitle({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
        child: Column(
```

If I don't give a height to the SizedBox as you see above, I get

```
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
```

I want this column to fill the remaining space. I tried changing from `SizedBox` to `Expanded` but I still get the same problem.

Comment: The `ExpandableListTitle` `Container` doesn't  have a height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use  of `shrinkwrap` property:

```
Expanded(
   child: ListView(
             shrinkwrap: true,
             children: [...],
          ),
)
```

Comment: I get `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.`

Comment: Parent `Column` must have `Expanded` child as well. I mean, root `Column` of the app.

Comment: @intraector is correct, all you have to do is Wrap the Container with Expanded

Answer (score 1):

Expanded has no size limit, same as Listview and Column. You have to put them inside a parent element that fills the entire viewport or atleast has a viewport with specific dimensions that you want the limitless child to fill.

**Container** with a width and height property is your best choice here.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
              children: [
                 ExpandableListTitle(title: widget.title),
                 Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 10, right: 5),
                    height: 280, // height specified
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, // width specified
                    child: ListView(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                 children: widget.children,
                            ),
                         ),
                      ],
                  );
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanded widget fills the available empty spaces to its full.[Click here to watch video about expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

List View is a widget that can grow infinite in size so, Expanded widget allows it to grow infinitely. This creates the error.

```
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
```

This error means that in vertical axis the height is unrestricted.

To avoid this type of error you need to use

> shrinkwrap = true

inside the ListView.Like this

```
Expanded(
     child:ListView(
            shrinkwrap:true,
            children:<Widget>
         [....]
    )
)
```

or else you can

> Spacer()

instead of listview, to avoid this error in column

```
Column(
     children:<Widget>
        [
           Container(child:Text("abc")),
           Spacer(),
          Container(child:Text("ccc"))
        ]
)
```